# UITableViewCell minimize and maximize animation

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a UITableView and when a cell is selected it reloads a different type of cell (to simulate the maximize and minimize effect). The problem is I cannot figure how to animate that properly since reloadData() method is called. I achieved some kind of animation using

```
UIView.transition(with: tableView,
                          duration: 0.35,
                          options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                          animations: { self.tableView.reloadData() 
})
```

but it's not really how I want it to look at the end. Did anyone do the same thing and has a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an animated change don't use reloadData.

Use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and specify the indexPaths that have changed.

Comment: that works pretty nice, but I can't seem to achieve a "natural" animation, all the UITableViewRowAnimationa look a bit broken. Do you mind providing a small example of a custom animation that would work?

Comment: I just use UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic which in the case of reloadRowsAtIndexPaths will be UITableViewRowAnimationFade.

Comment: ok, thanks, the method is great, but it is looking pretty awkward in my case because I have footers and they are being animated after the cell itself and they just fly around the screen after the cells are loaded